# OpenMP Parallelize code inside a for loop

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelize tasks inside a for loop using OpenMP. However, I do not want to use `#pragma omp parallel for` as the result of the (i+1)<sup>th</sup> iteration  depends on the output of the (i)<sup>th</sup> iteration. I have tried to spawn the threads inside the code, but the time of creating and destroying them every time is very high. An abstract description of my code is:

```
int a_old=1;
int b_old=1;
int c_old=1;
int d_old=1;
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
   a_new = fun(a_old);  //fun() depends only on the value of the argument
   a_old = a_new;

   b_new = fun(b_old);
   b_old = b_new;

   c_new = fun(c_old);
   c_old = c_new;

   d_new = fun(d_old);
   d_old = d_new;
}
```

How can I *efficiently* use threads to calculate the new values of `a_new, b_new, c_new, d_new` in parallel in each iteration ?

Comment: Assuming a, b, c and d are independent of each other you can have 4 different threads, one for each variable running their own `for` loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **don't** parallelize the code inside the for loop - move the parallel region to the outside. This reduces the thread creation and worksharing overhead. Then you can easily apply OpenMP `sections`:

```
int a_old=1;
int b_old=1;
int c_old=1;
int d_old=1;
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
       a_new = fun(a_old);  //fun() depends only on the value of the argument
       a_old = a_new;
   }
   #pragma omp section
   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
      b_new = fun(b_old);
      b_old = b_new;
   }
   #pragma omp section
   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
      c_new = fun(c_old);
      c_old = c_new;
   }
   #pragma omp section
   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
       d_new = fun(d_old);
       d_old = d_new;
   }
}
```

There is also another simplification:

```
int value[4];
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int abcd = 0; abcd < 4; abcd++) {
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        value[abcd] = fun(value[abcd]);
    }
}
```

In either case, you might want to consider adding padding between the values to avoid false sharing if `fun` executes rather quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried your solution and gives me good results. The only problem that I see now is that `fun()` does not take so much time, thus for a small workload it may be an overkill. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This pretty straight forward, as @kbr mentioned in the comments each of the calculation a,b,c and d are independent, so you can separate them to different threads and pass the corresponding value as parameter. The sample code looks like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_func(int *i)
{
    for (int j=0; j<1000; j++)
    {
        //Instead of increment u can call whichever function you want here.
        (*i)++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a_old=1;
    int b_old=1;
    int c_old=1;
    int d_old=1;
    pthread_t thread[4];

    pthread_create(&thread[0],0,thread_func,&a_old);
    pthread_create(&thread[1],0,thread_func,&b_old);
    pthread_create(&thread[2],0,thread_func,&c_old);
    pthread_create(&thread[3],0,thread_func,&d_old);

    pthread_join(&thread[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(&thread[1],NULL);
    pthread_join(&thread[2],NULL);
    pthread_join(&thread[3],NULL);

    printf("a_old %d",a_old);
    printf("b_old %d",b_old);
    printf("c_old %d",c_old);
    printf("d_old %d",d_old);

}
```

Comment: yadhu, I think OP wants explicitly to use OpenMP (possibly because its design is on minimising necessary changes on existing code, I am only speculating). Using pthreads seems an appropriate way, but seems not to be what OP is asking for.

Comment: Battu, please comment whether this is helpfully what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is a valid solution with pthreads. However, I am working on a solution that is more platform independent. If OpenMP is supported, then we can accelerate this part. If not, we have to go in a serial way. Thank you very much!